# How to install a masked package in Gentoo 2008?

Tags: installation, gentoo

I searched the net and handbook, but I only managed to learn what is the masked package, and not how to install it. I did find some commands, but they don't seem to work on 2008 (looking at it, it seems those are for earlier versions). I have something like this:

```
localhost ~ # emerge flamerobin
Calculating dependencies 
!!! All ebuilds that could satisfy "dev-db/flamerobin" have been masked.
!!! One of the following masked packages is required to complete your request:
- dev-db/flamerobin-0.8.6 (masked by: ~x86 keyword)
- dev-db/flamerobin-0.8.3 (masked by: ~x86 keyword)
```

I would like to install version 0.8.6, but don't know how? I found some instructions, but they tell me to edit or write to some files under /etc/portage. However, I don't have /etc/portage on my system:

```
localhost ~ # ls /etc/portage
ls: cannot access /etc/portage: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That is not about programing.

Comment: David, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962/system-administration-questions-yes-or-no

Comment: Besides, I'm a programmer, and need my tools up and running on Gentoo. So it is remotely related to programming. Just like if someone would have problems installing MSSQL server on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply mkdir /etc/portage and edit as mentioned here: http://gentoo-wiki.com/TIP_Dealing_with_masked_packages#But_you_want_to_install_the_package_anyway...

Comment: Does that mean:
echo "~dev-db/flamerobin-0.8.6 ~*" >> /etc/portage/package.keywords

Or:
echo "=dev-db/flamerobin-0.8.6" >> /etc/portage/package.keywords

Comment: echo "dev-db/flamerobin" >> /etc/portage/package.keywords

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore. Could you please update? I tried searching for "masked packages" in the Gentoo Wiki, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 6):

There are two different kinds of masks in gentoo. Keyword masks and package masks. A keyword mask means that the package is either not supported (or untested) by your architecture, or still in testing. A package mask means that the package is masked for another reason (and for most users it is not smart to unmask). The solutions are:

- Add a line to `/etc/portage/package.keywords` (Check `man portage` in the `package.keywords` section). This is for the keyword problems.
- Add a line to `/etc/portage/package.unmask` for "package.mask" problems (you can also use package.mask for the converse). This is in the same man file, under the section `package.unmask`. I advise to use versioned atoms here to avoid shooting in your own foot with really broken future versions a couple of months down the line.

Answer (score 4):

These days there's also a more 'automated' solution, called "autounmask". No more file editing needed to unmask!

The great benefit of the package is, it also unmasks / handles keywords of dependencies if needed. It's provided in the package app-portage/autounmask.

*/etc/portage/package.keywords* and
*/etc/portage/package.unmask*

can be directories as well nowadays (but autounmask handles single files as well). In those directories, multiple can place multiple "autounmask" files, one file in each dir per "unmask"-package. If you use single files instead of dirs, 'autounmask' will place some kind of header / footer, and this way it becomes easy to remove "unmasks" if wanted.